# Optional chaining for dynamic strings as property in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, optional-chaining

I have following sample code:

```
var x = [
{input1: "aaa"},
{input2: "bbb"},
{input444: "ddd"},
{input55: "eee"}
{input3: "ccc"},
]
```

I am trying to get values of props which if exists in the object something like

```
x.forEach((item, index) => {
 console.log(item.[`input${index}`]);
})
```

So for above sample code : I want output to be ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

I know the first part of the property (which in this example is 'input') and second part will be index only

Is it possible to know the values using Optional chaining? What I am missing?

Comment: Could you elaborate more please. Which values are you interested in getting

Comment: The initial object shows bad practice. You should never need properties to be constructed like <name + sequential number>. If you need values in a sequence, then use a flat array.

Comment: actually they are attribute of html tags which will come like this

Comment: It is also bad practice to give such pattern to HTML attributes.

Comment: What if the order of the objects in `x` is different and `input3` comes before `input1`?

Comment: Yes, it can happen, order is not defined
@trincot, agreed but it is legacy code and can u share some pointer how to give attribute names in a loop?

Comment: instead of having to guess what the property names are you could use an array like `[{name: "input1", value: "aaa"}, {name: "input2", value: "bbb"}...]`

Comment: You already accepted an answer, but there are still things to clarify, and the accepted answer assumes the order is defined :S. What if there is `input9` or `input11` or `input21`. When are you no longer interested in those? What if there is a `input5`, but no `input4`? Would you want an array with a gap?

Comment: yeah, you are right, as order is not defined, this answer will not work for it

Comment: Can you answer the other open questions?

Comment: yea, I am not interested in any other prop, only the one which will matches the string+index

Comment: What is the maximum suffix value that you consider correct? Like `input5` is OK, but `input6` is not? What if there is no `input1`, but there is `input2`? Should the resulting array have an undefined entry in its first slot? ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the order of the input is not guaranteed, I would do this:

```js
var x = [{input1: "aaa"}, {input2: "bbb"},{input444: "ddd"},{input55: "eee"},{input3: "ccc"},];

let result = Object.assign([], ...x.flatMap(o => 
    Object.entries(o).filter(([k]) => 
        k.startsWith('input') && +k.slice(5) >= 1 && +k.slice(5) <= x.length
    ).map(([k, v]) => 
        ({ [k.slice(5)-1]: v })
    )
));
    
console.log(result);
```

Some characteristics of this solution:

- Requires that the suffix in the property name lies between 1 and the length of the input array.
- Allows that some objects in the input array have no properties that match the pattern `inputXX`, while others may have multiple such properties.
- A value that is assigned to a property `inputN` will be stored at index `N-1` in the resulting array, even if that means there will be gaps in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You need just to add one to index and take bracket notation for the object without dot.

The [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) works only for having `undefined` source value. It does not switch  some program logic for either showing a value or not. In this case, you could check if the property exists in the object and then show th wanted part without some optional chaining

```js
var x = [{ input1: "aaa" }, { input2: "bbb" }, { input3: "ccc" }, { input444: "ddd" }, { input55: "eee" }];

x.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (`input${index + 1}` in item)
        console.log(item[`input${index + 1}`]);
});
```

Comment: agreed, it's better to check if exists or not, thanks!!

Comment: this one only works when order is defined

Comment: @MandeepSingh, you use an array. this is a datatype with a certain order. do i miss s/t?

Comment: @NinaScholz, i was editing the question for order, but I will still give you +1, bcoz it works for defined order which is generally the case

Answer (score 0):

Optional chaining makes little sense unless you are only looking for a specific property. Use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) or [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries).

```js
var x = [
  {input1: "aaa"},
  {input2: "bbb"},
  {input3: "ccc"},
  {input4: "ddd"},
  {input5: "eee"}
]

x.forEach((item, index) => {
 console.log(Object.values(item));
 console.log(Object.values(item)[0]); // If it is just one, reference it
})
```

If it has to match only if the index matches than it still does not require optional chaining to read the value.

```js
var x = [
  {input1: "aaa"},
  {input2: "bbb"},
  {input3: "ccc"},
  {input4: "ddd"},
  {input555: "eee"}
]

x.forEach((item, index) => {
 console.log(item[`input${index+1}`]);
})
```

And after your 5th or so edit, to get the output you want is even weirder.... You would need to use reduce OR map and filter. You need to keep track of the current index.

```js
const x = [
  {input1: "aaa"},
  {input2: "bbb"},
  {input444: "ddd"},
  {input55: "eee"},
  {input3: "ccc"},
];


let current = 1;
const out = x.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
  const key = `input${current}`;
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    acc.push(obj[key]);
    current++;
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(out);
```

Comment: You can remove the redundant `index`.